# how to re-install LDAP client in Debian?

Tags: debian, openldap

I have a system with Debian 11, and want to experiment with setting it up as an LDAP client for user authentication, following this: https://linuxhint.com/configure-ldap-client-debian/. However, about half-way through the configuration, that happens as part of the installation, I pressed the wrong key, which terminated the dialog I was in, and it went ahead and installed stuff.

I tried to remove the installation with `apt purge libnss-ldap libpam-ldap ldap-utils nscd` and install from the beginning - but now, it just powers through without showing the dialogs. I have tried to find all LDAP related files with `find / -iname "*ldap*"`, so I can remove them, but there doesn't seem to be anything relevant; what do I need to do to be able to re-install as if it had never been done before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog boxes were likely from `debconf` to help configure the installed packages.

If so, the options were saved into the `debconf` database and you should be able to see them using `debconf-get-selections | grep ldap`.  You can change the options using `debconf-set-selections`.

The `debconf` options should be removed when running `apt purge $PACKAGE`, but if that is not working you can manually purge `debconf` options using `echo PURGE | debconf-comminucate $PACKAGE` where `$PACKAGE` is the name of the package as shown in `debconf`.

While testing this, I noticed that `echo PURGE | debconf-comminucate libnss-ldap` did not remove entries for `libnss-ldap:amd64` so I had to run `echo PURGE | debconf-comminucate libnss-ldap:amd64` to remove those as well.

Once the options are removed, attempting to install the packages again interactively should prompt with the dialog boxes again.